# Why Connecting with SSH of VS Code I cannot open a specific folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually connect to remote computers through VS Code SSH. The settings (IP of the remote computer and public and private key pairs are properly set). The strange thing that is happening is that I can open any folder in the remote computer, but not the folder where the project is located (for example, I can also open the parent folder of the project).
It was working properly for years and now it has this type of problem.

Here, I report the output terminal:

```
[21:03:16.164] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[21:03:16.168] SSH Resolver called for host: PC000
[21:03:16.168] Setting up SSH remote "PC000"
[21:03:16.173] Using commit id "6261075646f044b98968d5000324gdhsdsjdd3b" and quality "stable" for server
[21:03:16.177] Install and start server if needed
[21:03:16.182] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[21:03:16.261] > OpenSSH_for_Wind
[21:03:16.262] > ows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[21:03:16.273] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 64484 "PC000" bash
[21:03:16.275] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

And after a while, it returns the timeout error.
I am putting the passphrase which it is requesting, then it is not able to connect to the folder.
Do anyone have some ideas?

I tried to open other folders with VS Code SSH connection and they are propery opened. I browsed with the command window to to the folder of the project and everything seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option? `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false`, for more details, you can have a look the discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1721#issuecomment-597783966)

Setting the `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` option to `true` solved the problem

Comment: I tried what you said, but it is not solving the problem. I found a difference for this folder than the others: now it does not prompt the request for the password (as I put the password for the couple of keys). Do you know how to solve this issue on requesting the password from the gui of VS Code? In the other folders I am opening the request for the password is showing out, correctly.

Comment: Am not sure what you mean, but is it a git repo or what? Did you run `git config credential.helper store` ? Then it will not ask for the password @sr__

Comment: When generating a private and public key pair, one can choose to put a passphrase too on them. So, when using the keys we have to insert the passphrase. If it is not prompting the window to insert the passphrase, the keys are not authenticated and then there is the timeout error. I tried also to set in settings.json "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true, though also with this setting the login terminal is not shown.